# jquery recaptcha php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I don't know how can i validate the recaptcha thing via jQuery. Please help. I have the contact us form with the following fields:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#signup').validate({
rules: {
name: {
required: true
},
email: {
required: true,
email: true
},
messages: {
name: {
required: 'FULL NAME Missing'
},
email: {
required: "E-MAIL ADDRESS Missing",
email: "E-MAIL ADDRESS Not Valid"
}

});



});


</script>

<form action="index.php" method="post" name="signup" id="signup">
<p>
Full Name
<br>
<input name="name" type="text" class="required" id="name" title="Type your Full Name into this box" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
</p>
<p>
E-Mail Address
<br>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" title="Type your E-Mail Address into this box" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>">


</form>
```

Validation with the jQuery is working, but no idea how to implement the recaptcha into this.

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/15563/jquery-validating-recaptcha-with-ajax/

Comment: Is the captcha library matters? I was able to implement it with [Securimage](https://github.com/dapphp/securimage) library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all for your comments,will get it done by simple library :)

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-captcha.php

And validation by using php after submitting of the form (it was easy for me to implement in less time in php than jquery. :) .

special thanks to Felix Kling  :).

Dave

Answer (score 0):

For those sort of validate, there is a validation method in `jQuery validate` plugin known as `remote`.

Check it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote)

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: "check-email.php"
    }
  }
});
```

In this `check-email.php` should return string "true" to be considered valid. and string "false" to be considered false.